# Adding bootstrap classes to video shortcodes

Tags: posts, functions, filters, hooks, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make videos responsive...

There is a function in /wp-includes/media.php file:
line 2497:

```
$html_atts = array(
    'class'    => apply_filters( 'wp_video_shortcode_class', 'wp-video-shortcode' ),
    'id'       => sprintf( 'video-%d-%d', $post_id, $instance ),
    'width'    => absint( $atts['width'] ),
    'height'   => absint( $atts['height'] ),
    'poster'   => esc_url( $atts['poster'] ),
    'loop'     => wp_validate_boolean( $atts['loop'] ),
    'autoplay' => wp_validate_boolean( $atts['autoplay'] ),
    'preload'  => $atts['preload'],
);
```

Not sure how to add this in my functions.php?

What I want to add is a hook (I guess) with this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

html that I have on the page at the moment is:

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" src="...">
```

I want to add or replace these with bootstrap ones.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I bootstrapped youtube embeds in one of my projects.

```
/**
 * Responsive Youtube embeds.
 */
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', function( $html, $url, $attr, $post_ID ) {
  if ( false !== stripos( $html, '<iframe ' ) && false !== stripos( $html, '.youtube.com/embed' ) ) {
    $html = sprintf('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">%s</div>', $html );
  }

  return $html;
}, 10, 4);
```

Please note this snippet is using [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which are available in > PHP 5.3